# What kind of Accuracy is needed?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been doing some reasearch on pi and eulers number and the calculations / programming involved. And I cannot find any information about what kind of accuracy you need for the devision.

For example:

1 / 120 = 0.008333333333333333

1 / 720 = 0.001388888888888889

You can tell that the number is a repeating number and will go on forever. So my question is when do you know when you have enough digit. Any thoughts would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Because of the way floating point math is implemented, you can never really trust it to accurately model fractions.  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  This is a non-trivial problem in the cases of numbers like `pi` and `e`, and involves some serious mathematics.  If you're limiting yourself to rational number (i.e. fractions) [this article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/02/25/project-euler-problem-26/) may prove to be a good starting place.

Comment: Which is the *Project Euler* problem number?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but it's useful information you may not know: Check out the `decimal` module in the stdlib. Unlike `float`, which has a fixed number of bits, `decimal.Decimal` has a configurable number of digits. So, once you work out how many you need for a given input, you can just set the precision and get the right answer, instead of calculating error bars on an approximation. Plus, of course, it lets you think in digits instead of bits, which, judging by your question phrasing, is probably going to be a big help.

Comment: @CristiFati Where did he say this was a Project Euler problem?

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry, I guess I got confused across comments (or I might be thinking of Euler?). I'll delete the faulty comment.

Comment: @CristiFati Does Project Euler have a problem number 2.71828…? If not, that seems like a major oversight. Then again, they should also probably have a 3.1415…, a 0, a 1, and an i, and I'll bet they only have one or two of those.

Comment: Another hint here: if you don't know about `fractions` in the stdlib, check that out too. It can do exact rational math, in the same way normal Python ints do exact integer math. It can get very slow and memory hungry if you're trying to evaluate lots of terms of a series, but you may find the results useful or interesting up to the point where it gets too slow. And also, SymPy (which you have to install off PyPI or Conda) is nifty for doing exact math on rational functions with irrational constants in them.